Spring Boot 3 resource server bypass proxy
I have Keycloak server running and a Spring Boot 3.3.5 application as a resource server.
I have configured https proxy host and port via environment variables for entire application via System.setProperty('https.proxyHost',...) because several dependencies in my application requires it.
Now all jwt token validation requests for resource server goes through the proxy and I get 403 forbidden. How I can bypass proxy for oauth2 resource server requests and set direct connection (rest template, http client) for resource server bypassing the proxy.
P.S. I can't unset system proxy properties.
